# How to do gradient descent for not all variables in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

In tensorflow, tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer does gradient descent for all variables in default. Can i just do gradient descent for only a few of my variables and 'lock' the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lock the ones that you don't want to train you can use `tf.Variable(..., trainable=False)`

Comment: Can i change the variables from trainable to non-trainable ones? I build a model with some parameters W and inputs X, after i train the W, i wanna these W to be fixed and make X to become new variables to maximize something inside the model, what can i do? Could i just rebuild the model, leaving a new W to non-trainable one and a new X as trainable variables, so that i could use Gradient descent optimizer to train these Xs?

Comment: Yes, just create a new Graph and a new session and initialize the new variables with the previous graph results.